# How do I automate building of a eclipse plugin and using third party jars

Tags: eclipse-plugin, maven-2, tycho

How do I automate the process of building my plugin and use my 'core' jar.

1) The 'core' is a maven project that has third party dependencies. This I have automated and am able to archive it to our a local 'Archiva' repo.
2) I have inherited a 'developer' plugin project which is/was manually built by a developer who is no longer with the company and very little documentation.
This project has now been "configured" to become a maven project using eclipse and using tycho able package its as an 'eclipse-plugin'. The structure of project is in image.[image]

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${tycho-version}</version>
<type>maven-plugin</type>
<!-- extensions>true</extensions -->
</dependency>
```

I know eclipse plugins only understands the bundles and can only be fetched from p2 repo but I have 'archiva' which is a maven repo? 
How do I make my 'core.jar' into a bundle and be 'p2'  recognizable?
I have read alot but just don't understand how to do it.

Hope someone can help me please?
regards,
jemrug

Comment: A Maven repository can not be used to build an Eclipse plug-in, e.g. because a Maven repository does not provide enough metadata to resolve `Import-Package` dependencies. So when using Tycho, p2 repositories (and old update sites) only are used to resolve dependencies. If you have a directory containing bundles/plug-ins JAR files, you can use the `tycho-p2-extras-plugin` to convert it into a local p2 repository (e.g. [see this example](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/master/mirror-non-p2/pom.xml)).

Comment: Could you please elaborate abit abit more so that I can understand, an example code would help?

Comment: Maven and p2 repositories are different things. A Maven POM script with Tycho uses p2 repositories only, a `pom.xml` without Tycho uses Maven repositories only. You can't mix that. But you can convert a `plugins` directory containing plug-in JARs into a p2 repository (see linked example in my previous comment). Maven dependencies are resolved at build time only, while p2/OSGi dependencies must also be resolved at runtime. Metadata (ID, dependencies, etc) are specified in Maven via the `pom.xml` file outside of the JAR, in p2/OSGi in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside the JAR.

Comment: As far as I know, Apache Archiva only supports Maven, but not p2 (in contrast to Nexus which supports both). Therefore, you cannot use your Archiva repository in your Maven+Tycho script.

Comment: If I the put the following:-    <project> .....etc
 <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
   <id>archiva.default</id>
   <url>http://m2420b:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
   <id>my.snapshots</id>
   <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
   <url>>http://m2420b:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
   <layout>default</layout>
  </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>
</project> I am able get that archive as a .zip that i can download and install. Hence its not a p2 repo.